# Which parameter to use in order to display several blocks?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07DPg.png)
I'm trying to define a zone in my word doc template and to display data from a record source(ERP Software), the problem I'm facing is that I can't show more than one block and I want to show the number of blocks that the database contains so I don't know which parameter to use, here is the picture which clarifies the subject, the picture contains my parameterized model and the result that we hope to get,

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your template is a DOCX and that you have defined the `p_experience` block using a table with 4 rows.

They are 2 simple solutions :

- Define the block on the 4 rows.
- Define the block on the table.

**PHP** :

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('p_experience', $data);
```

**Template** : simply add block definetion on the first TBS fields [p_experience.experience_job] (or any other TBS field in the block).

Block defined on the 4 rows :

```
[p_experience.experience_job;block=4*tbs:row]
```

Block defined on the table :

```
[p_experience.experience_job;block=tbs:table]
```

---

You will then have problem with the bullet list (*experience_description*) because for Ms Word, each item of the list is done with a different paragraph. So it cannot be done with a simple new lines in the contents of *experience_description*.

The solution is to use TBS sub-blocks.
See [manual](https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_subauto).